# Listen to iOS notification when the application is running in background mode

Tags: ios, notifications

My application is supposed to work in application mode but I would like to listen to some notifications, one example is CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification to monitor the change of the contacts.

The experiments show that the notification can only be received when the application is in foreground mode but not running in background.

Any suggestion how I can receive notification when the application is running in background?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean app in background mode or background thread?

Comment: I mean when app is running in background mode. Thanks.

Comment: I think you just add notification for observing in main controller, when you tap home button, app into background mode, and then if events come in, notification will have a callback.

Comment: I tried, it only received the notifications after it is foregrounded. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you have to open Remote Notifications in Background Modes on. See my screenshot below.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For any users, who want to receive notifications or background refreshing data, who have to light on the Remote Notifications or Background fetch, see above screenshot.